# IOS swift 4 expand and collapse tableview not working and causing crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Following is my code to add section header view cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuHeaderTableViewCellID") as! MenuHeaderTableViewCell
    cell.foodMenuItems = menuResult?.foodMenuItems?[section]
    cell.setParentUI()
    cell.expandCollapseClicked = {
        [weak self]
        (postiton) in
        let isCollapsed = self?.menuResult?.foodMenuItems?[postiton].isCollapsed ?? false
        self?.menuResult?.foodMenuItems?[postiton].isCollapsed = !isCollapsed
        self?.tableViewMenu?.beginUpdates()
        self?.tableViewMenu?.reloadSections([section], with: .fade)
        self?.tableViewMenu?.endUpdates()

    }
    return cell
}
```

Following is code for count in each row and section

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return (menuResult?.foodMenuItems?.count) ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let rowCount = menuResult?.foodMenuItems?[section].items?.count ?? 0
    let isCollpased = menuResult?.foodMenuItems?[section].isCollapsed ?? false
    return isCollpased ? 0 : rowCount
}
```

Following is code inside header view cell

```
@IBAction func expandCollapseClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let superView = self.superview as? UITableView else {
        return
    }
    expandCollapseClicked?(superView.indexPath(for: self)?.section ?? 0)
}
```

I am facing issue on collapsing first section my header disappears and when I try to collapase other section getting following exception how to fix this?

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (25), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
 *** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Why are you dequeuing a `UITableViewCell` in `viewForHeaderInSection` method? You need to return a `UIView` instance there instead of a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: You should return `cell.contentView`  instead of cell

Comment: button click closure not working if I return cell.contentView

Comment: @amodkanthe You should add tap gesture on `cell.cotenet view` and to identify which section tap you can set cell.contentView.tag = section

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be in :

1. Avoid `dequeueReusableCell`. Try to use UIView with label and button.
2. `expandCollapseClicked = {...}`
   should be called by UIButton. as it's sender is UIButton. Try to use:

   `view.button.expandCollapseClicked = {...}`

Hope this will work.